# Why is a auto_now=True field designed to not update when using QuerySet.update()?

Tags: django, django-models

from django:

> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.

Both will have to execute an update query, so what is the reason behind `save.()` updating the `auto_now=True` field and `QuerySet.update()` not updating the field?

Answer (score 1):

Update query is meant to be faster than the regular field changing and saving pattern, thus it does not call the `save()` method, which handles updating `auto_now` fields, sending signals and so on. If you're not sure what you're doing, then it's always a good idea to explicitly call the `save()` on a model. Advanced and "less restricted" methods such as `update` or `bulk_create` are faster and meant for editing data on DB level. From Django docs:

> Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and,
>   thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it
>   emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of
>   calling Model.save()).

If you were hoping for a more technical explanation, then the update query probably doesn't bother to check if the table has an `auto_now` field. It would require some data gathering and make the process slower. If you do want to update the field, you can update it explicitly.